# Multiprocessing: long vs short running workers

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying something with multiprocessing with a distributed queue. Is there a reason to choose `run` over `run2`? My feeling is `run2` is slightly more performant since it does not have the overhead of returning control to the main process.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from foo import my_distributed_queue as queue

def process_msg(msg):
  foo(msg)

def run():
  pool = Pool(4)
  for msg in queue:
    pool.apply_async(process_msg, (msg, ))

def process_msg2():
    for msg in queue:
      foo(msg)

def run2():
  pool = Pool(4)
  for i in range(4):
      pool.apply_async(process_msg2, ())

if __name__ == '__main__'
  run()
  #run2()
```

Comment: I believe `run2()` will only spawn a single worker...  (edit* I am quite confident in fact)

Comment: @Aaron good catch. I fixed it

Comment: anyway, I'm not sure there's a definitive answer here.. with `run2` there may be more overhead with accessing your queue from multiple sources (which would require some mutexes that I don't see here). Though again it would be spread out over multiple cores at least on the receiving end. on the other hand, you may starve your queue with `run`, as it will likely attempt to exhaust whatever iterable queue is as fast as it can, and store the args as pending jobs.

Comment: This a job for test cases and real world profiling...